# GSON crashes on Android 6.0 when decoding Intent with enum extra

Tags: java, android, android-intent, enums, gson

since the update to Android 6.0 I experienced some strange behavior of GSON.
I use Gson to decode the broadcast intent I am sending. Just for logging purpose.
This works fine on all android versions before 6.0:

```
Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sent Broadcast: " + CustomGsonBuilder.create().toJson(new Intent(BROADCAST).putExtra(EXTRA_ERROR, Test.KILL_ME)));
```

Test-Enum:

```
public enum Test {
KILL_ME
}
```

Gives me the output:

```
sent Broadcast: {"mAction":"de.alb.test.broadcast","mCategories":null,"mClipData":null,"mComponent":null,"mContentUserHint":-2,"mData":null,"mExtras":{"mAllowFds":true,"mFdsKnown":true,"mHasFds":false,"mClassLoader":{"packages":{"com.android.org.conscrypt":{"implTitle":"Unknown","implVendor":"Unknown","implVersion":"0.0","name":"com.android.org.conscrypt","sealBase":null,"specTitle":"Unknown","specVendor":"Unknown","specVersion":"0.0"}},"parent":null,"proxyCache":{}},"mMap":{"extraError":"KILL_ME"},"mParcelledData":null},"mFlags":0,"mPackage":null,"mSelector":null,"mSourceBounds":null,"mType":null}
```

On Android 6.0 Logcat shows:

```
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1038KB
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:147)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:534)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:307)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:205)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:899)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:899)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:899)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.346 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFact

10-13 10:29:45.508 21882-21939/? D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 1038KB
10-13 10:29:45.508 21882-21939/? D/Error: ERR: file=StringWriter.java
10-13 10:29:45.508 21882-21939/? D/Error: ERR: class=java.io.StringWriter
10-13 10:29:45.508 21882-21939/? D/Error: ERR: method=write line=147
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1038KB
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:147)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:534)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:307)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:205)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:899)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:899)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:899)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:899)
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error:   at 
10-13 10:29:45.530 21882-21939/? D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 3810980
10-13 10:29:45.531 21882-21939/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 3811064)
10-13 10:29:45.531 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
10-13 10:29:45.531 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3811064 bytes
10-13 10:29:45.531 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
10-13 10:29:45.531 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
10-13 10:29:45.531 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
10-13 10:29:45.531 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
10-13 10:29:45.531 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
10-13 10:29:45.531 21882-21939/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

CustomGsonBuilder:

```
public class CustomGsonBuilder {

public static final Gson create(){

    return new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setDateFormat(GlobalSettings.DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN).registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(byte[].class, new ByteArrayBase64TypeAdapter()).create();
}
}
```

This error is clearly related with adding the enum as an intent extra. Gson version is the same (2.3.1). Any hints on why this happens? Maybe some workarounds?

Comment: StackOverflow hints on some circular serialisation / deserialisation. Could you post the code where you setup/receive your Intent as well as calls to gson?

Comment: The relevant code is all there. See first snippet (Starts with Log.e(...)). I setup a new Intent with a static String and put some Extra to it. The resulting Intent is deserialised inside Log. (I simplified the code for this post. But this is the code to reproduce the problem)

Comment: Ah true, sorry, for overlooking that. I never really tried to serialise an Intent, but if it worked before, it should work now... Try setting @SerialisedName('kill_me') above your enum entry.

Comment: yeah, same for me. I just used this for debugging (displaying values of classes that I did not create). Tried putting `@SerializedName("kill_me")` on the enum, but the result is the same.